# Enterprise Library Caching 5.0 with Unity 4.0 doesn't build

Tags: c#, wpf, enterprise-library

I am migrating from Unity 2.0 to 4.0 because I need to upgrade to PRISM 6 which supports Unity >=4.0. The problem I am encountering is that EnterpriseLibrary 5.0 was built agaisnt Unity 2.0 and when I am trying to build the project I'm getting:

> Error 68  The type 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtension'
>   is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=2.0.414.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Here:

```
  container.AddNewExtension<EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension>();
```

I tried to create a `bindingRedirect`

```
  <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Unity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.414.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

It looks like `publicKeyToken` has been changed in >=Unity 4.0. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I moved to System.Runtime.Caching with FileCache nuget package. It looks like there is no solution for the above problem.